# Dynamic select latest date column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

There is a scenario as attached excel file, an issue progress daily tracker.
In Power BI, if I use a table visual, and want to only show the latest update(in this case will be 11/30/2018), how could I let it be done auto instead of selecting the date column manually?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better unpivoting that source data and storing the date as a value of a "date" column, rather than having separate columns for each date. Then you can use all the DAX time intelligence functionality.

You could use a query like this, to normalise your source data:

```
let
    Source = MyTable,
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"#", "Issue", "Owner"}, "Date", "Value"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"#", Int64.Type}, {"Issue", type text}, {"Owner", type text}, {"Value", type text}, {"Date", type date}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Value] <> null and [Value] <> "")
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Now your table view can be filtered using the Date field - if you want the latest date, then a `Top 1 by Latest Date` filter would work:

[image: Screenshot of table visual with date filter]

Comment: Is there any other way rather than unpivoting the table? Since I will need to keep adding in the date column.

Comment: Why does this technique prevent you from adding more dates?

Comment: It does not prevent. However, the data will get larger and larger, I am not sure whether it is a long-term solution.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? It would of course be preferable to enter / store your data in a normalised format, rather than continually increasing your columns. But this transformation will work with as many columns as your source can cope with.